# How can I read with SQL AS generic_name the Text of entries

Tags: sql, repeater

How can I read with SQL "Resim" the text of entries

Hi, I don't know to read the text of entries in a table. (I would like to use asp:Repeater)

got Error :

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Resim'.

My repeater

```
        <asp:Repeater id="MyRepeater" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>  

            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Model")%>  
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "car_pay_day")%>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Resim")%>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Galeri")%>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
```

---

MY SQL Query

```
SELECT  
Car.*, 
car_image_url AS Resim,
user_agent_name AS Galeri,
cma_name AS Marka ,
cmo_name AS Model,
cs_name AS Seri,
city_name AS Sehir

FROM    RentACar.dbo.Car

INNER JOIN RentACar.dbo.Users
ON car_user_id = user_id

INNER JOIN RentACar.dbo.Cat_Mark
ON car_cma_id = cma_id

INNER JOIN RentACar.dbo.Cat_Model
ON car_cmo_id = cmo_id

INNER JOIN RentACar.dbo.Cat_Series
ON car_cs_id = cs_id    

INNER JOIN RentACar.dbo.City
ON car_city_id = city_id            



LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT  Img.*
FROM    RentACar.dbo.Car_Image Img
INNER JOIN 
(   SELECT  MIN(car_image_id) AS Image_ID
FROM    RentACar.dbo.Car_Image
GROUP BY car_image_car_id
) AS MaxImg
ON MaxImg.Image_ID = Img.car_image_id
) AS Img
ON Img.car_image_car_id = car_id;
```

Comment: What date type is car_image_url?  It is an actual image or a link to the image.

Comment: string 

/upload/10CDoetopdeskUntitled23-11.png

Answer (score 0):

I used `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Foto")%>` and that worked.